# Can I change the pygame logo in the pygame window's titlebar?

Tags: user-interface, pygame, titlebar

Is there an option available to change the Pygame logo in the title bar of a Pygame window to my own program logo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`pygame.display.set_icon()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_icon):

> **pygame.display.set_icon()**
>
> *Change the system image for the display window*
>
> `set_icon(Surface) -> None`
>
> Sets the runtime icon the system will use to represent the display window. All windows default to a simple pygame logo for the window icon.
>
> You can pass any surface, but most systems want a smaller image around 32x32. The image can have colorkey transparency which will be passed to the system.
>
> Some systems do not allow the window icon to change after it has been shown. This function can be called before pygame.display.set_mode() to create the icon before the display mode is set.